# Is this a permutation or variaton or combination?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

The task is: You have two letters A and B, how you can order it with repetition ?

I know the result is 2 x 2 but I have no idea what category is it.
I've made some theory that it should be a permutation because n is not bigger than $p$, so I tried to solve it with the repetition permutation formula:  $2! /( 1! 1!)$ (the formula says divide it by the factorial of numbers that shows how much time the characters are repeated. A and B repeated just once in the list so why not ? It is logical... But of course it gave me a different result.

I don't really know what is going on...

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Your question is not clear.  What is a "cariaton"?  And what sort of words are you allowed to make? Can you make arbitrarily long words? If not what, limits the length?

Comment: If you are talking about two-letter words, you can have $2 \cdot 2$ words if you allow repetition: AA, AB, BA, BB. What's your question?

Comment: @Vasya yeah but the question is if this is this is a permutation or variaton or combination?

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  As you can see, nobody here can figure out what you are asking.  Also, "calculus of variations" does not mean what you think it means.

Comment: If we are talking about combinations, there are three category of it, these are named in my question.. so.. which one is this belongs to ?

Comment: You appear to be hung up on vocabulary, to the extent that you have lost track of the underlying meaning.  In any case, we can't tell you what sort of thing you are talking about unless you make it clear what you are talking about.

Comment: I am sorry, our teacher told us that every combinatorics problem can be classified to one of those three. (combination, variation, permutatuin) I don't know which one is it,

Comment: @rogogr: Are you asking how many different two-letter words are possible if we have one A and one B? Or you are asking how many different two-letter words are possible if we have two As and two Bs? Or you are asking how many different ways to put two letters in a box if you have a pile of As and a pile of Bs (in this case AB would be equivalent to BA)?

Comment: That's called a **word** of length $2$ from alphabet $\{A,B \}$

Comment: Nothing in the post refers to words of length $2$.  People are guessing that's what you mean, but that's really just a guess.

Comment: I don't really know how you not understand the question. It was not about fixing the problem itself, but to get the root of it by groupping to one of those three groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you managed to confuse yourself with the language: "how can you order A and B with repetition?"

On the one hand: when you say you want to 'order A and B', then it seems as if you already have 1 A and 1 B, i.e. you have a set of pre-existing objects ... and that would be about permutations: you arrange, but don't pick, since you already picked what you want to arrange.

On the other hand, once you throw in 'with repetition', you are suggesting that you no longer have a pre-existing set of objects that you merely want to rearrange (order), but rather you pick a first object that can be an A or B, and then a second that is an A or B .. that is, you seemed to use 'repetition' more like the concept of 'replacement' ... so now you pick *and* rearrange .. and so now it's about variations.

Comment: But as you can see http://users.telenet.be/vdmoortel/dirk/Maths/PermVarComb.html there are permutations with repetition.

Comment: @rogogr Ah .. but even there you have *pre-defined* sets, e.g. you are given 2 A's and 2 B's, and then you shuffle them, i.e. you always end up with 2 A's and 2B's total. And sure, that means you have *multiple* A's and *multiple* B's, which is the sense in which the author talks about 'repetition'.  However, you used 'repetition' in a different sense: you *pick* an object from a set as your first object, and then *replace* that object back into the set before picking the next object. So now you don't know how many A's and B's you end up with. That gives you variations rather than permutations

Comment: Thanks ! Now I maybe understand it.